# How to make setting of kern.ipc.somaxconn persistent?

Tags: freebsd, performance-tuning, sysctl

Want to rise value of kern.ipc.somaxconn

With sysctl works ok

```
$ sudo sysctl kern.ipc.somaxconn=2048
$ kern.ipc.somaxconn: 128 -> 2048
```

check it:

```
$ sysctl -a|grep somaxconn
kern.ipc.somaxconn: 2048
```

But if I set this value in /boot/loader.conf or /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf 
# $FreeBSD: src/etc/sysctl.conf,v 1.8 2003/03/13 18:43:50 mux Exp $
#
#  This file is read when going to multi-user and its contents piped thru
#  ``sysctl'' to adjust kernel values.  ``man 5 sysctl.conf'' for details.
#
kern.ipc.somaxconn="2048"
```

after reboot value of kern.ipc.somaxconn remains = 128

```
$ sysctl -a|grep somaxconn
kern.ipc.somaxconn: 128
```

How to make it persistent between reboots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes `"`

```
kern.ipc.somaxconn=2048
```

Test with `/etc/rc.d/sysctl start`

Answer (score 0):

If you've written the value into /etc/sysctl.conf it should be persistent between reboots - the file is read from on reboot, not written to.

You can try `sysctl -w kern.ipc.somaxconn=2048` instead. Also, how are you testing the change? Check:
`cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`

Comment: it should be persistent, but it's not with somaxconn, with other kernel values tunning all is ok

Comment: man sysctl `The -w option has been deprecated and is silently ignored`. 
Also its FreeBSD not Linux - forget about `/proc/sys`